# Finding firmware for a wireless router

Tags: wireless-router, firmware

I recently bought a *Tenda W368R* router, and I hated the current firmware! So I decided to find a open source Linux type of firmware. My router was not supported by DD-WRT ans a few others. But if my router is not supported, how do I choose firmware, similarities? Is there a sort of universal firmware? Which firmware should I get? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use 3rd party firmware, it has to support the chipset and other hardware inside your router.  You can try google or the manufacturer's website to see which wireless chipset your router uses, then see what options support that chipset.  The three big ones are DD-WRT, Tomato, and OpenWRT/Gargoyle.

Comment: So having a supported chipset means that the firmware say for another router that has the the *same* chipset will work?

Comment: This page is on DD-WRT's site, but the information is applicable to any firmware:  http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-detection

Comment: So having a supported chipset means that the firmware say for another router that has the the same chipset will work?

Comment: It means it may work.  Once you find firmware that support your chipset and hardware, search the forums to see if other users have had success with that router.  If all else fails, you can try yourself, but you risk "bricking" your router, making it useless.

Comment: Okay... What do you mean by supporting hardware?

Comment: I mean whether or not the firmware will work with all the components inside your router.  It's like drivers for the hardware in your PC.